# How to plot a Diagonal Histogram in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

Given scatter data, or a matrix, I would like to generate a nice plot such as the one shown below, with all 3 histograms and a colored matrix. I'm specifically interested in the diagonal histogram, which ideally, would correspond to the diagonals of a matrix:

[image: www.med.upenn.edu/mulab/jpst.html]

**Source figure**: [www.med.upenn.edu/mulab/jpst.html](http://www.med.upenn.edu/mulab/jpst.html)

The existing command *scatterhist* is not that powerful to generate this type of graph. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

Following @Cris Luengo's hints, I came up with the following code which does some first work at the inclined histogram: WORK IN PROGRESS (HELP WELCOME)!!

```
b = [0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10];
h = [0.33477 0.40166 0.20134 0.053451 0.008112 0.000643 2.7e-05 0 0 0  0];
wid = 0.25; bb = sort([b-wid b-wid b+wid b+wid]);
kk = [zeros(numel(h),1) h(:) h(:) zeros(numel(h),1)];
kk = reshape(kk',[1,numel(kk)]);

pp=patch(bb,kk,'b');axis([-.5 5 0 .5])
set(gca,'CameraUpVector',[-1,.08,0]);axis square
```

[image]

**EDIT 2: Using rotation**

```
phi = pi/4;
R = [cos(phi),-sin(phi);sin(phi),cos(phi)];
rr = [bb' kk'] * R;
bb = rr(:,1); kk = rr(:,2);
patch(bb,kk,'b'); axis([-.5 3 -4 .5])
```

[image]

Comment: This will require quite a lot of hand "hacking" of the plotting functions. There is no easy way.

Comment: The figure source says that you can request the code from the authors. Have you tried that? Also, I suggest you take a look at the visualization capabilities of the [Bioinformatics toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/bioinfo/examples.html) (although I haven't seen anything exactly like what you need, there are other types of visualizations you might find useful).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recipe to plot the diagonal histogram, if you can do that I’m sure you can figure out the rest too.

1. Compute the histogram, the bin counts are `h`, the bin centers are `b`.
2. Build a coordinate matrix, attaching the coordinates of a point on the x-axis at the left and right ends of the histogram:

   ```
   coords = [b(:),h(:)];
   coords = [coord;b(end),0;b(1),0];
   ```
3. Using [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) you can now plot the histogram as follows:

   ```
   patch(coords(1,:),coords(2,:));
   ```
4. To plot a rotated histogram you can simply multiply the `coords` matrix with a rotation matrix, before using `patch`:

   ```
   phi = pi/4;
   R = [cos(phi),-sin(phi);sin(phi),cos(phi)];
   coords = R * coords;
   ```

You might need to shift the plot to place it at the right location w.r.t. the other elements.

I recommend that you place all these graphic elements in the same axes object; you can set the axes’ visibility to 'off' so that it works only as a canvas for the other elements.

It will be a bit of work to get everything placed as in the plot you show, but none of it is difficult. Use the low-level `image`, `line`,`patch` and `text` to place those types of elements, don’t try to use the higher-level plotting functions such as `plot`, they don’t provide any benefits over the low-level ones in this case.

Comment: Thanks Cris! Something's seems wrong with the definition of the coords matrix though. For instance, using these vectors, b = [0     1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    ];10; h=[0.33477      0.40166      0.20134     0.053451     0.008112     0.000643      2.7e-05            0            0            0 0]; I get a faulty patch....

Comment: @Oliver: oops, I wrote the construction of the `coords` array wrong, sorry. The two points added are supposed to be on the x-axis (i.e. be at y=0). These complete the polygon so it has an edge going along the x-axis and underneath the data line.

Comment: @Oliver: if you rotate the axes, you won’t be able to add the non-rotated elements. Modify your coordinates to rotate the histogram, instead of rotating the axes!

Comment: @Oliver: set the x and y axes to scale equally (`axes equal`). And turn off the visibility of the axes because they no longer represent the data correctly. The original figure doesn’t have those either.